# How to enable VT-x for Docker on MacPro 2008

Tags: mac-pro, virtualization, docker

So I've read that it is possible to enable Virtualisation on MacPro 2008 however I do not find how.

I know that I have VMX since the output of `sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features` is :

```
machdep.cpu.features: FPU VME DE PSE TSC MSR PAE MCE CX8 APIC SEP MTRR PGE MCA CMOV PAT PSE36 CLFSH DS ACPI MMX FXSR SSE SSE2 SS HTT TM PBE SSE3 DTES64 MON DSCPL VMX EST TM2 SSSE3 CX16 TPR PDCM SSE4.1
```

But I think what I need to enable is the virtualisaiton support which I can check with : `sysctl kern.hv_support` and output me

```
kern.hv_support: 0
```

So how can I enable it ? I've tried to install the EFI update from [this official link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203296) but it tell me than the update is "not necessary".

Comment: Where have you read this? Source or link? My understanding is virtualization is inherent in the CPU and main boards / PCI bridges or equivalent. Short of putting a new CPU / logic board you get the capabilities of the Mac as it was made.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU in the Mac Pro 2008 does have VT-x support, so the CPU has the capability in itself.

However, you need to update the EFI firmware to actually enable the support so it can be used from macOS / OS X. You'll need to update to version 1.3.

You can find the download link here:

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL95?locale=en_US

You can find the official explanation from Apple here:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203296

If you already have the EFI update installed, then VT-x should be enabled by default.

If it still isn't you can find the source code for a program on the link below that will both tell you the current state (enabled/disabled) for each CPU-code, and then turn on VT-x.

https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Enable_VT-X_on_Mac_Pro_(Early_2008)

The program requires you to be running Linux on the Mac Pro. You could also run a virtual machine (although slowly without VT-x) in order to run the Linux program from there.

The last thing to try if you cannot get the official EFI updater to install the EFI update, is to flash the firmware manually by following the instructions on this link:

https://pubmem.wordpress.com/2011/04/09/flash-efi-firmware-update-manually-on-a-macbook-51/

However, this is very risky if you don't know what you're doing. You risk bricking the computer if you flash the wrong file.

Comment: Sorry, only now realized that you have already tried the EFI update. Will update with more info.

Comment: the vtx linux tool will not work from a vm - just tried in my virtualbox vm